# Angularjs UI grid not checking ng-show condition when row gets updated

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using angularjs ui grid, I have field called status in my code, where user can update the status to either Active or InActive by clicking on button.

After update I am able to refresh the data, but celltemplate: condition is not getting fired. I am using below method to refresh ui grid

```
$scope.gridOption.data=data;
$scope.gridOptionApi.core.refresh();
```

but this is only refreshing my data, its not checking the condition which I have added in celltemplete which is as below

```
 {field: 'profileId', displayName: 'Change Status',cellTemplate:'<div class="text-center">
<button ng-click="grid.appScope.changeProfileStatus(COL_FIELD, \'InActive\' )" ng-show={{row.entity.status==\'Active\'}} 
class="btn-custome-warn custom-btn-xs  btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></button><button 
ng-click="grid.appScope.changeProfileStatus(COL_FIELD, \'Active\')" ng-show={{row.entity.status==\'InActive\'}} 
class="btn btn-xs btn--small custom-btn-xs button--primary"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button></div>'}
```

so basically I am showing change status field where if the status is active then I am showing button for Inactive it and vice versa.

Anyone any suggestions please?

**here is plunker i tried to create to show u demo, but status here I am now updating manually to show you else I have api call for updating it, if you see data is changing but status change buttons are not changing**
[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/iS8BOWsWI4CUAlapcy8P?p=preview)

Comment: I got the same issue with ng-show and ng-hide, try ng-if as an alternative, it may help. Some issue happens with ui-grid refresh

Comment: i tried with ng-if its not displaying anything then, not even html buttons also, so only I am using ng-show

Comment: Does `ng-show` need quotes like `ng-show="{{row.entity.status==\'Active\'}}"`?

Comment: ng-show="{{row.entity.status==\'Active\'}}" and ng-show={{row.entity.status==\'Active\'}} , both ways I tried, data is getting refreshed but buttons are not changing, which should change based on condition

Comment: @Icycool here is plunker i tried to create to show u demo, but status I am now updating manually to show u else I have api call for updating it, if you see data is changing but status change buttons are not changing
http://plnkr.co/edit/iS8BOWsWI4CUAlapcy8P?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got plunker to work by changing
`ng-show={{row.entity.status==\'Active\'}}`

to `ng-show="row.entity.status==\'Active\'"`

Reason being anything inside `{{ }}` is executed inside the template immediately so you can see generated html has `ng-show="true"` but not an expression like

`ng-show="row.entity.status=='Active'"`